# Unable to read response Content in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit

I am trying to write a really simple unit test in ASP.net core 2.2 using NUnit. Here is the Get:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Cars()
{           
    return Ok( new { Cars = new BusinessLayer().GetListOfCars() } );
}
```

The return type of `GetListOfCars()` is `List<Car>`. Where `Car` is a class with a `Name` and `Model`.

Here is my Unit test:

```
[Test]
public void CarControllerTest_GetAll()
{
    CarsController myController = new CarsController();

    var response = myController.Cars();

    var result = response as OkObjectResult;

    Assert.AreEqual(StatusCodes.Status200OK, result.StatusCode);
}
```

Above test is working fine but how can I read the content of the response as I need to verify the number of records as well.

I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
var carlist = result.Value as List<Car>;
```

Comment: you could use dynamics `dynamic model = result.Value; var cars = model.Cars as List<Car>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var carlist = result.Value as List<Car>;
```

did not work because you have the data wrapped in an anonymous object.

```
new { Cars = new BusinessLayer().GetListOfCars() }
```

Use dynamics to extract the desired property

```
dynamic model = result.Value;
List<Car> carlist = (List<Car>)model.Cars;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the return type to return List<Cars> instead of wrapping it in another object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a small flaw by using dynamic to extract the desired property suggested by Nkosi .

You could try to use reflection to read data like below:

```
var result = (response as OkObjectResult).Value;

var carlist = result.GetType().GetProperty("Cars").GetValue(result,null);
var list = carlist as List<Car>;
```